# How to do error handling in PowerBuilder 5?

Tags: powerbuilder

What is the commonly used syntax for error handling in PowerBuilder 5? There is a lack of online help for PowerBuilder 5 because it is too old. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code your own errorhandling.  Generally methods will return an integer or null to indicate either success, failure, or a null parameter.  You will have to check these and react accordingly.

After any database call you should check the SQLCode return value of your transaction object in case the statement failed.